# Set of subsets notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Why is it that we denote the set of all subsets of $A$ by $2^A$?

Is there any historical or logical cause that motivated this notation?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/129303/856

Comment: @Rahul Interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another reason is that the set of all subsets of $A$ can be identified with all functions $A\to \{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}$ is sometimes called $2$. Plus the common usage of $B^A$ to denote the set of all functions $A\to B$.

Comment: Why is it called $2$?

Comment: @Peter, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory

Comment: @PeterT.off: In pure set theory, each natural number is defined as the set of all smaller natural numbers, and so $0=\emptyset$, $1 = \{0\} = \{\emptyset\}$, $2 = \{0,1\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, etc.

Comment: @jwodder Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Motivation: the cardinality is $2^{|A|}$.