# What does $\mathbb R^S$ mean when $S$ is a set?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the meaning of a set to the power of another set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129301/whats-the-meaning-of-a-set-to-the-power-of-another-set)

What does $\mathbb R^S$ mean when $S$ is a set? I am reading a text and I wonder if it has a special meaning or it's just a typo? Note that $\mathbb R^{|S|}$, where $|S|$ is the size of $S$, makes sense in the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As anon points out, it is just notation for the set of all functions $S \to \mathbb{R}$. When I first saw this notation, I found it confusing, but one of the benefits is that

$$\left|B^A\right| = |B|^{|A|}$$

where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality. You have to use cardinal arithmetic for infinite sets, but it still works.

A special case of this relationship is the fact that $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = 2^{|A|}$. To see this, first note that there is a $1-1$ correspondence between subsets of $A$ and functions $A \to \{0, 1\}$ given by the indicator function ($1$ if it is in the subset, $0$ if not). Then we have:

$$|\mathcal{P}(A)| = \left|\{0, 1\}^A\right| = |\{0, 1\}|^{|A|} = 2^{|A|}.$$

Answer (score 4):

I would interpret it to mean the set of functions from $S$ to ${\Bbb R}$.

Comment: Also, if $[n]$ denotes the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, then we can canonically identify $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{[n]}$, so the notation is consistent with the more familiar notation.

Comment: Hmm, I always thought of $n$ as being synonymous with $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, which means that ${\Bbb R}^n$ is just ${\Bbb R}^n$.