# Notation for Sample Space

Tags: probability, notation

Consider an example of flipping a coin infinitely many times. In class, the following notation was used:

$$\Omega=\{H,T\}^{\mathbb{N}}$$

Although I understand what $\Omega$ is supposed to look like, (infinite numerations of the infinite combinations of Heads and Tails), what is the sense/logic behind this notation?

Comment: Does the space notated include the combinations where a coin is flipped only _finitely_ many times (HT, THH)?

Comment: No, this is the entire sample space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129301/whats-the-meaning-of-a-set-to-the-power-of-another-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sets $A$ and $B$, the notation $B^A$ is used for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$.  (Possible reason for this is that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $\mid B^A \mid = \mid B \mid^{\mid A \mid}$, where $|S|$ is the number of elements in set $S$).

A sequence of coin tosses can be regarded as a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{H,T\}$ where $1\mapsto$ first toss, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot..However, why is the mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to ${H,T}$? Using your notation, isn't set $B$ an infinite set?

Comment: If you have a sequence of heads and tails, say HHT..., then the mapping would be 1 to H; 2 to H; 3 to T; etc.  Corresponding to the notation in my answer: $\{H,T\}$ is $B$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is $A$.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!